# How to target earlier non-sibling element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       <figure>
           <img class="overlay" src="...">
       </figure>
       <figcaption>
           <h3><a href="...">Text</a></h3>
       </figcaption>
   </li>
</ul>
```

When I mouseover the `h3` inside the `figcaption`, I want to alter the opacity on the image `class=overlay` inside the `figure`. Good lord, surely this is simple but I've been doing my nut in trying

```
$('h3 a').mouseover(function(){
 $(this).closest('.overlay').css('opacity',1);
});
```

and changing closest to prev, prevAll, etc., all with no success. Any help will be met with jubilation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the following method

```
$('h3 a').mouseover(function(){
 $(this).closest('li').find('figure .overlay').css('opacity',1);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
$(this).closest('li').find('.overlay');
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/. Generally speaking, you just need to browse that category to find the correct combination of traversal functions to use.